# How to run a script using diff for a command?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terminal, diff

I'm writing a script to test a program and I'm getting caught at this portion

```
if (("$x"==22)); then
    echo "Checking for whether wrong input file is detected."
        if diff   ${arr[$x]} <(./compare ); then
            echo Output is as expected.
        else
            echo Output is not as expected. Check for errors.
        fi
    else
        if diff -q  ${arr[$x]} <(./compare $i); then
            echo Output is as expected.
        else
            echo Output is not as expected. Check for errors.
        fi
    fi
```

So what it's doing is testing my program against known output. However, for the case where I use ./compare without an argument, I want to receive an error message from my program specifying that the argument is missing. The test file it's using, "22" let's call it result22.txt, has the exact same output my program would give from just running ./compare (no arguments). However, when I run it using the script, it says that result22.txt differs from just running ./compare. I'm pretty sure I"m running the script wrong, any ideas?

Additionaly information, i is a known input test file that's from an array, x is an incremental variable to count which loop we're on. So arr[$x] is just accessing the nth file from the known output files.

Compare is my own compare program to run.

Comment: What does `bash -x` give? Otherwise your script is fairly unclear. What is `$i`? How are you avoiding an infinite loop (assuming this script is `compare`, otherwise, what's compare...)?

Comment: Added some explanation, there's no infinite loop occurring, I've limited the loop.

Comment: Do you have DOS line endings in the file? What differences does `diff` show you?

Comment: If `compare` writes its error message to standard error (like it should) you need to redirect it; you are capturing and examining the program's standard output.